Google Cloud API does not recognize my Expo SHA-1 fingerprint
I tried setting up an API-key for Google Cloud that can be used from my Expo-managed android app. I got the fingerprint by running eas credentials and set the restriction in Google Cloud to only Match android apps with this fingerprint.
When implementing react-native-geocoding, I got the following error when trying to fetch data from the API:
this ip, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this api key. request received from ip address XX.XX.XX.XXX, with empty referer with status REQUEST_DENIED.
When I remove the restrictions for the API-key, I can easily access the API.
What could be causing this? Am I maybe using the wrong fingerprint for the development version? If so, where can I find the correct one?

Have you created android key or browser key?

@Suraj I used Expo EAS to build the app which generates the key. For another build, I used expo prebuild, which led to another key being created that also didn't work

Run .\\gradlew.bat signingReport or ./gradlew signingReport to get the SHA-256 fingerprint. While you might have restricted the API key to a specific IP address, which makes no sense for a mobile application: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key
Instead of a completely unrestricted API key, one should put a public web-server in between.
